# Difference between Vdd and Vref?

Tags: adc

What is the difference between VDD and VRef in the context of ADCs?

[image]

Comment: What did the chip datasheet said about it when you read it? Chapters 3.8 and 3.9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vdd is the power supply for the device.

Vref is the reference voltage for the ADC. The conversions are relative to that voltage and it determines the size of the LSB. It would normally be an accurately controlled voltage, maybe from a voltage reference device.

The specific relationship between the voltage at the Vref pin and the input voltage range varies with the device.

For unipolar binary ADCs Vref is often equal to the maximum voltage that the ADC can handle and is divided into 2^n steps (where n is the number of bits resolution).

For the MCP3302 it is described in section 3.8 of the datasheet. The LSB is 1/4096 of the Vref voltage. Be careful about interpreting this for the MCP3302 and similar devices as it accepts differential inputs with a resulting signed digital output but the inputs must not go beyond the ground or Vdd rails. In unipolar mode it acts as an unsigned unipolar ADC with one part in 4096 resolution (ie 12 bits).

In many ADCs (including the MCP3302) Vref can be connected to Vdd to use the power supply as a reference, in some ADCs it may be connected internally to Vdd and a Vref pin is not provided.

Answer (score 5):

VDD is the 'main' power supply input -- it supplies the current to operate the ADC. Its value typically does not have to be particularly precise -- maybe ± 5% or even 3 to 5 V for example.

VREF is the reference for the ADC and needs to be accurate in order for the whole ADC to be accurate (the ADC converts VIN/VREF to a binary value; if VREF is off, the binary value is off).